# Why is my UIActionSheet hidden by my TabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am having a problem correctly implementing a UIActionSheet in an iPad 5.1 (XCode 4.3) project.  I can populate it correctly with all the items I need.  The list is longer than the window, but the scrollbars automatically come up, etc.  However, the cancel button (which I presume is supposed to be at the end) is coming up half hidden behind my tab bar.  Shown below:

(sorry, SO won't let me post images yet)

Here is my storyboard setup:
The entry point is that Tab Bar Controller on the left, which goes to another Navigation Controller (center), which has the View Controller on the right as the root view.
http://i854.photobucket.com/albums/ab103/srVincentVega/ScreenShot2012-06-28at52713PM.png

I have tried presenting the UIActionSheet in all sorts of ways, but this odd behavior persists, and I can't figure out how to address it

```
- (IBAction)cmdReason:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *reasons = [AppState getInspReasons];

    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Reason for Inspection"
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for (NSString *rsn in reasons)
    {
        [action addButtonWithTitle:rsn];
    }

    [action showInView:self.view];
}
```

I have tried the various methods to show "action" - showFromTabBar, showFromToolbar, etc - I am VERY new to this development environment, so I am not up to speed yet on how these items interact at this level.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can present this correctly?

I am sorry if this has already been asked elsewhere.  I have spent all day trying bits of code from all over the web, including SO.  I don't know if it's something to do with my storyboard layout, or what.

One further thing - when I rotate the emulator, the action sheet does redraw, but the bit at the end there gets wonky looking, like it can no longer figure out how to draw it.

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have put together a very small project that demonstrates this exact behavior.  I don't have a good way to host the zip file, so I put on google docs and shared it.  The link is below.  If you click on that, there should be a download option under file that will give you the original zip file.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7IYvy9_c_NLaEFneGc5bzc2S2c

Comment: It's hard to tell UI issues while not seeing this. Is it possible for you to make a very small demo project?

Comment: Tomorrow I can try to put together a new project with this exact scenario, it should not take long.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Hm yeah this is a interesting problem. The best i could do is to show sheet from the button, this way you could see half of cancel button. Even showing it from TBC's view doesn't fix the problem. I would guess, this is due apple's recommendation on not showing cancel on iPad at all.

Comment: if i give it nil for the cancel button, and then add a final button with just the text "CANCEL", it still cuts off half of it (as you say).  I don't know, maybe this will be good enough, since you can just tap outside of the action sheet anyway to dismiss it.  I really wish I could figure out why this is.  My app is going to have a lot of these select-one actions (trying to replace not having a dropdown list), but maybe I am better off just doing this with a popover view.  Although I hate how heavy that is

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is not a real solution for this. It looks like it's a limitation with `UIActionSheet` if you add that amount of button titles and present that from a tab bar.

Beside that, the proper way to display an `UIActionSheet` from a tab bar is to use

```
[action showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

instead of

```
// Taken from your example project
AppDelegate *d = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *w = d.window;
UIViewController *vc = w.rootViewController;
UITabBarController *c = (UITabBarController *)vc;
UITabBar *t = c.tabBar;
[action showFromTabBar:t];
```

Comment: I have tried many methods of showing it, including the one you suggest.  none of them work.  I have to agree with you, this seems like a limitation.  I'm just surprised I ran into one.  I've been playing with XCode for a week...  maybe I will try to find an apple forum and see what they say.  it would be nice to have confirmation

Answer (score 0):

I would think if you got a reference to the tab bar controller then you should be able to present it from that. You can try showing it from the main window but I would think you shouldn't rely on that.

```
[action showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

Comment: I saw some other information out there that said something similar.  I am not entirely sure how to "get" to my tab bar controller from this particular view.  I even read something like when controllers are nested like this, there's no direct chain, you have to go through the AppDelegate or something (which I am not familiar with).  I tried your code line, and I get the same problem:  http://bit.ly/MWlYxb   what's weird is that no matter what view I feed it, it still does this.  I am not 100% sure I have successfully referenced the master tab bar controller yet, though. any help there?

Comment: If you look within your applicationDelegate.h file (This will probably be a different name for your project) you should see a tabbarcontroller which is your root controller I assume. From that you can access it through your app Delegate and present the action sheet from its view.

Comment: my file is named AppDelegate.h, and there is very little in there.  I created a brand new tabbed application, and it created the exact same file.  No direct references to the tab bar controller.  I feel like I am missing something trivial... 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h); //change values to fit location of button
[actionSheet showFromRect:r inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

I used it on one of my apps with the same problem and the dismiss button showed up ok.

Comment: that's a good idea, I may try that - although I feel like I need to understand why my current implementation is not working, first.  More than just getting past this, I am trying to learn this stuff well.  Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep it handy